# Conditional Formatting Based on Cents

Tags: javascript, acrobat, conditional-formatting

I am trying to set a condition that, if the sentence (a mixture of words, symbols, and numbers) ends in ".96", all the text turns to specific color. If it ends in anything else, it's another color.

Here is what I have so far. Currently, I have some number conditions in there because that's what I know how to do:

```
var mf = this.getField("myField");
if (mf.value = 0.96) {
  event.target.fillColor = [ "CMYK", 12, 60, 98, 1 ];
} else {
  if (mf.value >= 10 && mf.value < 20) {
    event.target.fillColor = [ "CMYK", 18, 92, 100, 8 ];
  } else {
    event.target.fillColor = [ "T" ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try with "endsWith" method, like this:

```
var mf = this.getField("myField");
if (mf.value.endsWith(".96")) {
  event.target.fillColor = [ "CMYK", 12, 60, 98, 1 ];
} else {
  if (mf.value >= 10 && mf.value < 20) {
    event.target.fillColor = [ "CMYK", 18, 92, 100, 8 ];
  } else {
    event.target.fillColor = [ "T" ];
  }
}
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/endsWith).
Greetings.